# A perfect hash for known values

Tags: c, hash

Say I have some known values, against which I want to create a hash table. For example,

```
For 0x78409 -> 1
For 0x89934 -> 2
For 0x89834 -> 3
```

etc...

But these values (0x78409, 0x89934, 0x89834) are only known at runtime, so *switch/case* cannot be used. However, they become known at the beginning of execution, so maybe we can create a hash function which adapts itself to make a perfect hash table. So my question is, can we create a perfect hash function for such case.

Comment: What are you doing with this hash table? Since you can enumerate all the keys that you will use, you may want to use a different data structure, such as a pre-computed trie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the entire domain of inputs is known before the hashmap is created, then this is possible, but requires some form of runtime code generation, either via a VM or JIT (probably through a scripting language, such as LuaJIT), that would allow you to use [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/s/gperf/) and its ilk to create a hash at runtime, compile it, then use it to fill and retrieve from the map.

An easier, more viable solution is to use a hash function with extremely low collisions for the given set of input permutations (ie: you might only be using alphabetical, lowercase characters for instance), a minimal perfect hash.

Murmur3 and crapwow are the ones to lookout for (though, I'd be cautious with crapwow), [Google's CityHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CityHash), and [xxHash](http://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash/) are also worth looking at. Bob Jenkins also has a good minimal perfect hash based map available [here](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html), which should do just fine as well.

Comment: +1, I'd also recommend a look at [CMPH](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/index.html), which allows you to build (optionally minimal) perfect hash tables at runtime.

Comment: That link to team5150.com is dead, and redirects to malicious sites.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia gives [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). But are you sure you want a perfect hash function? Perhaps a good and fast hash function can be enough?